# Toggling from MapView(2D) to SceneView(3D) using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.0?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am currently working on a 3D map. I am wondering if it is possible to create a drop down list to toggle between 2D to 3D map.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange.  Please edit your question to explain what you have tried and where exactly you're stuck.  The more information you provide, the more we can help you.

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=views-switch-2d-3d) But I have encounter a problem while changing view. I create a new view every time view changed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/123809)